# Hide or disable a service on specific version in manifest

Tags: android, android-manifest, wear-os, android-wear-data-api

Is there a way to disable a Service in a certain Android version? I don't want versions 4.2 and lower which do not support Android Wear to launch my WearableListenerService.

Is there a way to say, "I don't want to launch this Service if you are on version 4.2 or lower"?

```
<service android:name=".MyWearableListenerService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.BIND_LISTENER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do it.
As version that don't support Wear will NOT use Wear sync capabilities [WearableListenerService](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/WearableListenerService) won't be run anyway.